# "Нарушений не установлено" или "нарушения не установлены"?

Tags: склонение, управление, подчинительная-связь

Во фразе

*Нарушений судами норм материального права, как и процессуальных норм, в том числе являющихся в силу ч. 4 ст. 288 Арбитражного процессуального кодекса Российской Федерации безусловными основаниями для отмены судебных актов, судом кассационной инстанции не установлено."*

окончания в словах "нарушений", "не установлено" каким правилом объясняются?

По мне, так "нарушения ... не установлены". Вот подобные, широко употребляемые фразы:

*Между тем в рассматриваемом случае арбитражным судом подобныХ нарушениЙ не установленО.*

*Приведенные заявителем в кассационной жалобе доводы отклоняются судом кассационной инстанции, поскольку не опровергают выводОВ судов о недоказанности истцом заявленных требований...*

*ОснованиЙ для применения к заявленной сумме неустойки положений ст. 333 Гражданского кодекса Российской Федерации судами не установленО.*

*НадлежащиХ доказательстВ,  опровергающиХ  данные обстоятельства ТУ Росимущества суду не представленО...*

Answer (score 3):

1) **Не опровергают выводов (Р.п.)**

Это тема у Розенталя: [§201. Падеж дополнения при переходных глаголах с отрицанием](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/66.htm#%D0%B7_04)

Родительный падеж ― это подчеркнутое отрицание, отвлеченные существительные, книжная речь. Винительный падеж ― это ослабленное отрицание, конкретные существительные, разговорная речь. Также рассматривается влияние других факторов.

**2) Нарушения не установлены ― нарушений не установлено.** Это две возможные грамматические формы: пассивная и безличная. В юридической речи чаще используется безличная форма, которая по смыслу соответствует сочетанию "нарушений нет".

Возможно такое объяснение. Форма "нарушения не установлены" может пониматься как "нарушения не найдены, без гарантии, что их нет.